# Programmatic login via request.login() doesn't redirect to <form-error-page> in case of fail

Tags: jsf, redirect, jsf-2, authentication, jaas

I'm working in a web app that implement login with Request.login(). The problem is if the login fails the jsf does not redirect to form-error-page. If I use the tradictional method j_security_check everthing works fine. Is there some type of detail to make the same with managed bean login?

```
ExternalContext externalContext = externalContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
request.login(username, password);
```

In my web.xml

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>security_domain</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/pages/login.xhtml</form-login-page>           
        <form-error-page>/pages/loginError.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Comment: You are interested in the new Servlet 3.0 programmatic authentication hereby not the form based authentication. In programmatic authentication, you are supposed to redirect to an error page programmatically as well. Thus, the case is considered to be normal.

Comment: I see. I'm trying to make the same magic. Well, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When not directly submitting to `/j_security_check` URL, the `<login-config>` is basically entirely ignored, including the `<form-error-page>`.

Deal with it yourself:

```
try {
    request.login(username, password);
} catch (ServletException e) {
    externalContext.redirect(externalContext.getRequestContextPath() + "/pages/loginError.xhtml");
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, for UX it's actually considered better to stay in the same page with just an error message shown in the form.

```
try {
    request.login(username, password);
} catch (ServletException e) {
    facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Unknown login"));
}
```

Comment: As usual explanations are always clear and objective. Many Thanks.